# Creating an Array in VBA - Returning "Sub or Function not Defined"

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to create an array to copy a column of data, however the column being copied is subject to change depending on the month being used. The table is titled by month number (1,2,3,4), what I've tried to do is set a StartingPoint (being the first cell in the array) and an EndPoint (being the last cell in the array), with the idea being to then reference each to create the array to be copied.

However, when I try to run it I'm getting a Compile Error to say "Sub or Function not Defined", which I've never seen before. I've tried researching online but all of the info I've found advises to check the "Solver.xla" box within Referencing, but there is no Solver.xla option to check!

The code I've written is below. If anyone can please assist and / or provide any useful tips or links to read up on it would be much appreciated.

For reference, it is Offset that is being highlighted when the error appears.

```
Dim ws7 As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws7 = ActiveSheet

Dim StartingPoint As Range
Dim EndPoint As Range
Set StartingPoint = Range("C58:R58").Find(ws7.Range("C3"))
Set EndPoint = Range(StartingPoint, Offset(10, 0))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Offset is a member function of Range. Try `Set EndPoint = StartingPoint.Offset(10, 0)`

Comment: Thanks Vincent. That has worked in a sense, though now it's returning "Object variable or With block variable not set". I've done a quick bit of research that said the Find in Starting point may be returning 0. I don't think it is, but need to run that code separately to be sure.

Comment: Add a ```Nothing``` check ```If Not StartingPoint Is Nothing Then
    Set EndPoint = StartingPoint.Offset(10, 0)
End If```.

Comment: Thanks Dee, that's sorted now.

Comment: Since doing the above and now trying to copy the data, I'm receiving a "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" error. My research advised to specify the sheet being used using             With and         End With, which I've done but to no avail. Code as follows;           With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tables")
Range(StartingPoint, EndPoint).Copy
End With           Any tips on why this might be?

Comment: My apologies, I'm unsure how to set the text format to differentiate between code and question (ie font and greyed out).